# Django user is_authenticated vs. is_active: when should I use one or the other?

Tags: python, django

After reading the documentation, I still don't fully grasp the difference between these two `User` methods: [is_active](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active) and [is_authenticated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests).

Both are returning a boolean. While `is_authenticated` is read-only (and you get an error if you try to set it), `is_active` can be modified and for instance you can set it to False instead of deleting account.

Running these commands, will de-activate a user:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> u = User.objects.get(pk=10) # get an arbitrary user   
>>> u.is_active
True
>>> u.is_active = False # change the value
>>> u.save() # save to make effective
>>> u.is_authenticated
True
```

Now, this user is still authenticated but is not able to login anymore.

The login view uses `authenticate()`. What is actually happening that the login for a de-activated user fails?

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password1']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
```

To verify the credentials you use `authenticate()` which returns a `User` object in case of success or None otherwise. I guess it returns None in case the supplied credentials are correct but `is_active` is False.

In addition, the Jinja block `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` evaluates as false if `is_active` is False, which is confusing when I think that `user.is_authenticated` is True and read-only.

**Question recap**:

When a user is de-activated, `is_active` is false and `is_authenticated` is (always) true. What is actually `authenticate()` checking if the user is not active but authenticated? Is it because `is_authenticated` is an alias for checking that the user exists? But then why is `{% user.is_authenticated %}` even false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`is_active`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active) is an attribute on user accounts which can be flipped on and off. You can do that in the admin interface, or programmatically. Only active users are allowed to log in. I.e. you can use the `is_active` flag to prevent a user from logging in without needing to change their password, delete their account, or do anything else drastic.

[`is_authenticated`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) is an attribute of the specific user class being used. If you have actual `User` objects, their `is_authenticated` attribute is always `true`; it's a statically set attribute on the `User` class.

The `is_authenticated` attribute is relevant only on user objects on requests:

```
def view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        ...
```

If the user of the request was *not* authenticated, `request.user` would not be a `User` object, but an [`AnonymousUser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#anonymoususer-object) object, whose `is_authenticated` attribute is always `False`. The idea here is that `request.user` always exists, regardless of whether a user is currently authenticated or not. This means you don't need to write code like `if request.user is not None and request.user....`. You can always expect a user object to exist, and you can distinguish between authenticated and unauthenticated (anonymous) users with the `is_authenticated` attribute.

Comment: On a side note, we often don't access `is_authenticated` directly. Instead we use the `@login_required` decorator. (In case it isn't clear, this comment is more for the OP and future visitors than for the answerer.)

Comment: It is more clear. Actually, I am trying to see if I can use `is_active` for user verification, i.e. create a de-activated user and activate only after verification. I suppose this is the correct way.